# Extract bitmap (or bitmapdata) from Shape

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, shapes, simplebutton

I got an swf that has SimpleButtons in the stage, and I need to get the bitmap or bitmapdata information from the button states.

When I load the symbol, it seems that no matter what composes the button states, they are all shapes, at least that's what I get in the expression panel.

So, how can I get the bitmap or bmpdata from a Shape?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`BitmapData#draw()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#draw%28%29) to get `BitmapData` from any `DisplayObject`. BitmapData is raster, so be aware you will lose features of the vector `Shape`

```
var bd:BitmapData = new BitmapData( shape.width, shape.height );
bd.draw( shape );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting FP 11.6 I'd use the method graphics.readGraphicsData as explained here http://www.bytearray.org/?paged=6